# Fetching a bean from business logic in a JSP (using expression language)

Tags: jsp, el

I have a JSP which takes a single parameter (a user ID) for which I retrieve the user details via a business logic call within a scriptlet; I then present the retrieved details in various form fields:

```
<%@page import="temp.UserLogic"%>
<%@page import="temp.User"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<%
    User user = new UserLogic().getUser(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("userId")));
%>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label>ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="<%= user.getId() %>">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" value="<%= user.getUsername() %>">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text" value="<%= user.getPassword() %>">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to to ditch the scriptlets in favour of EL.  Obviously, my form fields would be straightforward enough:

```
<input type="text" value="${user.id}">
<input type="text" value="${user.username}">
<input type="text" value="${user.password}">
```

However, I'm struggling as to what I use instead of this line of code:

```
User user = new UserLogic().getUser(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("userId")));
```

I've seen the useBean tag which is great if I just want to instantiate and populate a new bean but in this instance I want that bean to come from business logic.

This sort of pattern must be so common but I've spent hours trawling the net without an answer... any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well the Business Logic bean - UserLogic - doesn't really have any place in your JSP. This should be called in your back-end code and this back-end code should then simply place the User in scope for the JSP.

The MVC (Model View Controller) pattern is what you are looking for.

In a Servlet this would look something like:

```
//Servlet Acting as Controller
public LoadUserServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        //Controller Loads the Model
        User user = new UserLogic().getUser(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("userId")));
        request.setAttribute("user", user);

        //Controller Forwards to the Next View
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/userEdit.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And your JSP then simply becomes:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label>ID:</label>
        <input type="text" value="${user.id}">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" value="${user.userName}">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text" value="${user.password}">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There are of course may Java MVC frameworks that will simplify a lot of the boiler-plate code required when working with raw Servlets.

Comment: "Well the Business Logic bean - UserLogic - doesn't really have any place in your JSP. This should be called in your back-end code and this back-end code should then simply place the User in scope for the JSP".

So does this mean that I need to use a servlet to service my "View User" request and then forward from the servlet to the JSP (with the user bean now in scope)?

Comment: Yes: look at the MVC pattern (Model View Controller). See, for example: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Comment: Would vote up if I had the power!  Thanks for your help Alan Hay.